# How does project tag formatting affect a POM file and it's ability to draw dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I've been trying to get oriented with Spring Boot, Maven, and Couchbase for work so I've been researching it and building some tutorials. Something interesting that I've run into is that seemingly the same project tag with slightly different formatting can cause the POM file to not work correctly, and thus cause errors in all the classes that draw from the dependencies.

I first ran into this problem with a prior project. After troubleshooting for a long time, I knew it had to be a POM issue and not Maven because other projects were working fine with Maven. I noticed that the only error in the POM file was the starting **project** tag was underlined (literally just the word project, nothing else in the tag). I fixed it by copying the project tag from a functioning project and replacing it.

So this happened again with another project that I'm working on now. I tried the same fix and it didn't work. But copying the **project** tag from a different functioning project did work.

After scanning through the tag, I can't understand why this happens. For the record, all the code I'm posting has been provided to me through the spring.io tutorials, so I find it especially interesting that I have to work around this.

Here is a before and after of a POM file that wasn't working, but is working with a different heading. I am working in IntelliJ.

Malfunctioning Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-accessing-data-rest</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Functioning Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-accessing-data-rest</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Can someone help me understand why this would happen? Keep in mind, both of these project tags worked in some project, be it this one, or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differerence is

```
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd
```

versus

```
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd
```

IOW, the broken one has `/xsd/` in it.

Comment: You can access `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd` via browser perfectly...also the other one works as well...

Comment: Do they have same contents? Does the broken pom work if you change the URL?

Comment: They both work in some POM file. The broken one works in a different POM file, but not in this one for some reason. The other POM has different contents.

Comment: If you hover over the underlined "project", do you get a message?

Comment: Yes, I don't have access to the exact phrasing at the moment, but it essentially says that there is an error with syntax.

Comment: I feel like I'm seeing a different error message now, but right now it's saying "Failed to read artifact descriptor from [...]" I'm working on a different project now, and that's what this one says.